# flink task manager how to pre init few settings

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I need to download Keystore and use it while creating the source connector, currently, I am overriding open [method](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/99c2a415e9eeefafacf70762b6f54070f7911ceb/flink-connectors/flink-connector-kafka/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kafka/FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.java#L560) but this gets called for each of my source connectors.

```
 @Override
    public void open(Configuration configuration) throws Exception {

  // do few things like download Keystore to default path etc 
 super.open(configuration)
}
```

Is there an option to init a few pre stuff as soon as the task manager came up?